# Removing large files from file upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, reactjs

I would like to allow a user to upload multiple files through Ajax. If some of the files are too large I would like to remove them from the upload list. How can I go about doing this? I currently have the following for my input field.

```
<input id="file" type="file" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} required multiple />
```

So far I have come up with something like this to verify which files are too large:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;

    if (target.type === 'file'){
        console.log("FILES")
        const files = target.files
        console.log("The following files are too large")
        for (let i=0; i < files.length; i++){
            if (files[i].size > 50000){
                console.log(files[i].name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing I am confused about is how files are handled, as they are not really links to the actual files on the file system. How does the file structure work? How can I store the good files into a new file structure that is uploadable with Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

`target.files` is just an array. You can simple filter it, removing the files you don't want and do whatever you want with the new array (e.g. store it in the component's state).

```
const files = target.files.filter(file => file.size <= 50000);
this.setState({files});
// or uploadFiles(files)
```

If you are asking how to actually send files via an XMLHTTPRequest, this can be done with [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData):

```
const data = new FormData();
files.forEach(file => data.append(file.name, file));
```

and then send the `FormData` object via the XMLHTTPRequest.